# Can predictors with little relationship with target still be useful for a model?

Tags: interaction, predictor

For example, do interaction effects mean that it is still worthwhile to train a model with predictors which do not have much of a relationship with the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for an explanatory variable to carry little or no information about the response on its own, but be highly informative in combination with other explanatory variables.

A famous, simple example is the exclusive-or (XOR) function. Say we have two binary input variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$. Suppose they're independently generated by flipping a fair coin for each. A binary output $Y$ takes the value $1$ if $X_1 \ne X_2$ and $0$ otherwise. Notice that the inputs jointly determine the output--given both $X_1$ and $X_2$, you know with certainty what $Y$ will be. But, each input variable on its own carries no information about the output--given the value of $X_1$ or $X_2$ alone, $Y$ can't be predicted any better than chance.